# Java: Check if numbers are in a specific range

Tags: java, numbers, range

I have an integer array with five values, sorted in ascending order with no duplicates. I want to check if three of the five values that are in the array meet the requirement that they are in a sequence but don't all have to.

If three of the group of numbers below are in the array of five numbers the requirement is met:

`(1, 2, 3, 4)`
or
`(5, 6, 7, 8)`
or
`(9, 10, 11, 12)`
etc.

So the following arrays return true:

EXAMPLES:
`(1, 2, 3, 18, 40)`
or
`(2, 3, 4, 20, 34)`
or
`(1, 3, 4, 7, 12)`
or
`(9, 11, 12, 31, 51)`

While the following arrays return false:

EXAMPLES:
`(3, 4, 5, 11, 29)`
or
`(15, 16, 17, 33, 42)`
etc.

The "rule" is that three numbers in the array of five numbers must be within the respective range, 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5, 6, 7, 8 etc. but I don't know how to go over this

Could someone please help me with this?

I will be forever grateful!

**EDIT (since as a new user I can't post an answer to my own question so soon):**

Okay, I have found a partial answer: First I check if three cards have the same rank.

I check if cards 1 to 3 have the same rank. If not, I check if cards 2 to 4 have the same rank. If not, I check if cards 3 to 5 have the same rank. Here is my code:

```
// check
if (tempArray[0] == (tempArray[1] - 1)) {
    System.out.println("1. and 2. card match");
    if (tempArray[1] == (tempArray[2] - 1)) {
        System.out.println("2. and 3. card match");
        // three cards of same rank, starting from the first
        if (...) {
            isThreeOfAKind = true;
        }
    }
} else {
    System.out.println("1. and 2. card DO NOT match");
    // toak could start from the second card
    if (tempArray[1] == (tempArray[2] - 1)) {
        System.out.println("2. and 3. card match");
        if (tempArray[2] == (tempArray[3] - 1)) {
            System.out.println("3. and 4. card match");
            // three cards of same rank, starting from the second
            if (...) {
                isThreeOfAKind = true;
            }
        }
    } else {
        // toak could start from the third card
        System.out.println("2. and 3. card DO NOT match");
        if (tempArray[2] == (tempArray[3] - 1)) {
            System.out.println("3. and 4. card match");
            if (tempArray[3] == (tempArray[4] - 1)) {
                System.out.println("4. and 5. card match");
                // three cards of same rank, starting from the third
                if (...) {
                    isThreeOfAKind = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you notice that I left out the if clauses. There I have to check if the numbers are within the range (1-4, 5-8, 9-12, etc.) but I have no idea.! But the code is still faulty because for example 1, 3, 4 are not recognised as the same ranks even though it's valid

Comment: Start by describing the steps to solve the problem in words (i.e. use whatever *natural* language you are most comfortable with). If you can do this, then translating into Java becomes much easier.

Comment: You will not become a better java programmer if you try to get an answer for a homework. Use @Code-Guru's advice. Think smart and you will feel nice if you solve this! :-)

Comment: Yes, I will try and do that now. By the way, this is not any homework or the like, it's just for a little poker game I'm currently making :) (Three of a kind) I'll go at it now!

Comment: Sorry, your solution will not work for 1,3,4,5,6 (which should return true for 1,3,4 according to your question. Check my answer below, in which I do an integer division by 4; each value in each group will have the same result and therefore be in the same grouping. However, if it is a poker game, I would model the cards properly, each with 2 fields or more, instead of mapping them to a single int.

Comment: Yeah, create a class with a "suit" and a "value" field instead of using simple ints. Will make all your code more readable too.

Comment: Luis yes you are right. I tried your code but it doesn't work for me (see my reply to your answer below pls)

Comment: Joe I'm using a card class. The values that are in the int array are actually from the card values. I'm only using that int array to evaluate the poker hand :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public boolean check3InARow(int[] array) {
  int currentResult = (array[0] - 1) / 4;
  int countCurrentResult = 1;
  for (int i=1; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (((array[i] - 1) / 4) == currentResult) {
      countCurrentResult++
      if (countCurrentResult == 3) return true;
    } else {
      currentResult = (array[i] - 1) / 4;
      countCurrentResult = 1
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: According to the question "The array is sorted in an ascending order"

Comment: Thanks for this. I tried it but it doesn't work. For example: 13, 14, 15, 20, 48 which is valid for 13, 14, 15 spews out false but it should be true

Comment: You are right; I missed a set of parenthtesis in the inner if (within the loop). I have fixed it

Comment: Aww thanks man. I would have never figured out such a function! I will go through the code now and try to understand it. Thanks a bunch!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution - I think it would be helpful:

```
    public class CheckConsecutivity {

        public static boolean checkConsecutivity(int[] array) {
          final int NUMBER_OF_CONSECUTIVE_FOLLOWERS = 3; // this constant make the method general to check if any number have
                                                    // any number of consecutive followers; just change to the number you wish 4 or 10 e.g. 
          int count = 1;
          int currentPos = 0;
          for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[currentPos] == array[i]-count) {
                System.out.println("Current Value = " + array[currentPos] + "; next value = "+array[i]  + "; count = " + count);
                count++;
                if ( count % (NUMBER_OF_CONSECUTIVE_FOLLOWERS + 1) == 0) {
                    System.out.println(NUMBER_OF_CONSECUTIVE_FOLLOWERS+" consecutive followers of "+array[currentPos]+" have been found :)");
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                count = 1;
                i = currentPos++ + 1;
            }
          }
          System.out.println("consecutive numbers have not been found :(");
          return false;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          int[] test = {7, 15, 10, 11, 12, 13, 1, 3, 4};
          int[] test1 = {4, 3, 2, 1};
          int[] test2 = {100, 101, 102, 17, 12, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7};

          System.out.println("\nTest evaluated to true++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++:)"); 
          checkConsecutivity(test);

          System.out.println("\nTest1 evaluated to false------------------------------:("); 
          checkConsecutivity(test1);

          System.out.println("\nTest2 evaluated to false---------------------------------:(");  
          checkConsecutivity(test2);
        }

    }
```